# Javascript fade in not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a bit of javascript to fade in a couple of message bars at the top of my page - a bit like stackoverflow does :)

I have:

```
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Wow, that was quick! - below is a preview of your page.</span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a>
</div>
<div id='message' style="display: none;">
    <span>Try posting something interesting</span>
    <a href="#" class="close-notify">X</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#message {height:30px;width:100%;z-index:105;text-align:center;color:white;padding:10px 0px 10px 0px;background-color:#8E1609;}
#message span {text-align: center;width: 95%;float:left;}
.close-notify {white-space: nowrap;float:right;margin-right:10px;color:#fff;text-decoration:none;border:2px #fff solid;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px}
.close-notify a {color: #fff;}
```

and Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#message").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#message a.close-notify").click(function() {
        $("#message").fadeOut("slow");
        return false;
    });
});
```

But unfortunately only the first message displays. How come? Surely the second one should show as well?

thanks

Comment: I think you have the answer lol!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` attributes should be unique among all elements in the page. Change the HTML, CSS and JavaScript to use `class="message"` instead of `id="message"` and it will work fine.

Technically what happens here is that jQuery sees the `#message` selector and tries to find the element using `document.getElementById` (which is fastest). This function returns only one element, in this case the first one. So the second never has a chance to be processed.

**You also have a bug:** As the code stands now, hitting the "close" link will make *all* messages disappear. You need to tweak the `click` handler a bit to make it behave as expected.

**[See all of this in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/p6rrm/)**.

Answer (score 2):

An ID should only be used once on the page. It is a unique identifier.

You'll want to use a class instead if you have multiple items.

**Html**

```
<div class="message">Some Message</div>
<div class="message">Some Other Message</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.message').fadeIn('slow');
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GBjxH/

Answer (score 0):

Both of your elements have the same ID #message - an ID should be unique, so this should be a class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an ID for two elements, try using a class!

```
<div class='message' style="display: none;">

$('.message').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because they both have the same id. The fadeIn is only being called for the first one. If you want to do it for both (or all) of them, apply a class and do something like

`$(".classname").each(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two identical ID's

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have elements with the same 'id'.

Answer (score 0):

ID's are unique! You cannot have 2 Elements with the same ID. Use Classes

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have multiple items with the same id, use a class instead.